# pyodbc hive can't set properties

Tags: hive, pyodbc

Has anyone run into issues attempting to set hive properties through pyodbc and the properties not taking?

I'm able to connect to my Hive server and run queries that would indicate a session is remaining open (eg. using temporary tables).

However, when I try:

```
set hive.mapred.mode = nonstrict;
```

or

```
set hive.execution.engine = mr;
```

Neither of these properties get set.

Thoughts?

Comment: Solved: Driver mismatch. Was using a Hive 2.x driver for a Hive 1.2.x environment.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following: `set hive.hive.mapred.mode = nonstrict;`